# How can I implement autocomplete within a comment?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am building a vscode extension that automatically completes the jsdoc syntax inside a javascript comment.
So I tried adding an autocomplete trigger with registerCompletetionItemProvider, but it didn't work as expected.
It works fine because it triggers outside the comment, but it doesn't fire at all within the comment.
[image]

Could you get any advice on this?

Comment: `"editor.quickSuggestions": { "strings": true  }`

Comment: I confirmed it works fine.
But as I understand it, the method is what the user has to set up. Is there any way the extension can handle it?

Comment: That's correct, you should very well leave it up to the user as it's their choice. Good job researching that! However, you can always set a default in your package.json: `"contributes": { "configuration": { "[javascript]": { "editor.quickSuggestions" : {} }` they can always change it and their user preferences should take priority iirc. Orrr you could implement some kind of logic and control flow to determine if the user is currently in a comment and go from there via getting doc text or regex parsing the line etc